# Unable to Install tensorflow-text on Raspbian

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I need to install [tensorflow-text](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/) on a Raspbian machine and I'm facing some issues.

- Python version: `3.7.3`
- Tensorflow version: `2.2 (installed from source)`
- Pip version: `20.2.4`

When I try to install from `pip`, I get:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text
```

So I then tried to install the package manualy [downloading it's files](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/#files), but it's wheels are all x86_64 and Raspbian is running in a 32bit machine so I'm not sure what can I do to install this package, I've seen many people tring this by their own but I couldn't find any valid solution, any ideas?

Comment: Your only option is to compile the package from source AFAIK. There's no official support for ARM from the devs, but at least I was able to build a wheel on a RPi once.

Comment: Yes it seems to be the only solution. I'm not even sure how to do this but I'll figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Start with the [`run-build.sh`](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/blob/master/oss_scripts/run_build.sh) and google on eventual errors; you may need to adjust the bazel job config for ARM-specific stuff etc.